# Audio cuts out periodically when using audio hat

Tags: pi-3, python, i2c, pi-zero-w, alsa

I am currently live streaming some audio to and from a raspberry Pi Zero W using the waveshare audio hat however I have found that the audio periodically cuts out when I do this. When I used my logic analyzer on it I found the the I2C stream seems to stop sending data to the hat periodically. Here is what the data stream looks like for the Pi Z and the Pi 3
[image]

The PIZDin is the I2C data in from the Pi Zero and you can see that it cuts out frequently and the Pi 3 on PI3Din cuts out some as well. You can also see that the audio input from the Pi Z is constant. The data is continuously streamed even when the I2C stops sending it to the audio hat. Here is the driving code:

**Sender on Pi Z W**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import alsaaudio
import socket
import struct
import sys
from gpiozero import Button

#button to start broadcasting
button = Button(17)

#prepare audio devices
device = "default"

audioIn = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, device=device, periodsize=1, format=alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)
audioOut = alsaaudio.PCM(device=device, periodsize=1,format=alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)

#prepare network connection
broadcastIP = ('192.168.100.255',10000)
recieve_group = ('',10000)

cast = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cast.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

#read data and play it locally and broadcast to network
while (True):
   if (button.is_pressed):
      length, data = audioIn.read()
      audioOut.write(data)
      # broadcast data
      print(len(data), sys.stderr)
      cast.sendto(data,broadcastIP)
```

**Reciever on Pi 3**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import alsaaudio
import socket
import struct
import sys

#prepare audio device
device = "default"

audioOut = alsaaudio.PCM(device=device,periodsize=1,format=alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)

#prepare network connection
receive_group = ('',10000)
receive = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

receive.bind(receive_group)

#read data from network and play it on audio hat
while(True):
   data, address = receive.recvfrom(65536)
   audioOut.write(data)
   print(len(data),sys.stderr)
```

I can't figure out why it is cutting out does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt purge pulseaudio` and rebooting. It can sometimes cause problems with audio output.

If it's not installed, try running `sudo apt install pulseaudio` which ironically can also fix things.

Comment: Pulseaudio was never installed on my system so I can't remove it

Comment: Then try installing it

Comment: I'm using alsaaudio through libasound2-dev and the python library pyaslaaudo

Comment: I could use pulse audio but since it is Livestream I'm going for minimal latency and from what I've seen the latency from pulseaudio can be significant